How to calculate revenue by sales team if sales agents change teams?
    Agents
    ID | Agent
    1  | A
    2  | B
    
    Teams
    ID | Team
    1  | AA
    2  | BB
    
    Memberships
    ID | AgentID | TeamID | Start Date | End Date
    1  | 1       | 1      | 2023-01-01 | 2023-12-31
    2  | 1       | 2      | 2024-01-01 | 2099-12-31

    Clients
    ID | AgentID
    1  | 1

    Orders
    Date       | ClientID | Rev
    2023-02-02 |      1   | 10
    2024-02-01 |      1   | 20

How to get the following table based on the above?
Team | Rev
AA   | 10
BB   | 20


As mentioned by @nbk, there is no need to denormalise memberships to achieve what you want. If you do, you risk having conflicting information in memberships and orders. I changed some of your attribute names:
select t.team, sum(o.rev)
from memberships m
join teams t
  using (team_id)
join agents a
  using (agent_id)
join orders o
  on o.order_date between m.start_date and m.end_date
group by t.team;

I used Postgres in the following Fiddle, but it shouldn't be too difficult to adapt it to the DBMS that you use
If your DBMS supports temporal business time, you may consider using that for this type of scenario. One advantage is that you can easily prevent overlapping intervals.

One solution would be to add the membership as a column in orders:
Orders
Date       | ClientID | Rev | Membership
2023-02-02 |      1   | 10  |  1
2024-02-01 |      1   | 20  |  2

